# Get only one paragraph from post through RSS

Tags: rss, mailchimp

I googled and googled try to find something relevant but no luck.

I'm setting up a 'daily tips' campaign for a client and I have to use RSS to do it.

In more detail I use MailChimp and I create a RSS-Driven campaign.
On the other side in the blog of the website there are daily scheduled posts.

I'm trying to find a way to only get the first paragraph of the each post to give it to MailChimp and include it in the email.

So that the structure ends up like this:
Post title
Post's first paragraph
Read more link

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you change your RSS feed to only include the first paragraph? I don't believe it's possible to truncate the content from the RSS feed from within MailChimp.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Would I be able to achieve that by manipulating the RSS Feed itself?

Comment: Yes, that would be my recommendation. Perhaps create an alternate RSS feed that you use just for importing to MailChimp. In that RSS feed truncate the content to pass only what you want to MailChimp.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible within Mailchimp  directly, but you you might try **[FeedsAPI](http://www.feedsapi.org)** if you have a specific feed, even perfect if it's a not so popular feed since they can create specific extraction patterns for cases like this, it's however a paid service.